# Promtail basic auth using kubernetes secret in helm values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, logging, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I am using the promtail helm chart to connect to a Loki server running on a different stack. I have Loki behind an Nginx ingress secured with basic auth.

I can't find any documentation on this, and it's very possible it's just my admittedly limited understanding of helm.

I'm simply trying to use basic auth to connect to the Loki instance while using a Kubernetes secret instead of plaintext credentials in the helm values

This works perfect:

```
  snippets:
    extraClientConfigs: |
      basic_auth:
        username: myusername
        password: mypassword
```

I created a secret like this:

```
kubectl create secret generic loki-credentials -n monitoring --from-literal=password="mypassword" --from-literal=username="myusername"
```

and now I want to use that in the `values.yaml` file.

This is what I got so far:

```
extraEnv:
  - name: LOKI_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: loki-credentials
        key: username
  - name: LOKI_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: loki-credentials
        key: password

extraArgs:
  - -client.external-labels=stack=development
  - -config.expand-env

config:
  serverPort: 3101
  lokiAddress: myurl
  snippets:
    extraClientConfigs: |
      basic_auth:
        username: ${LOKI_USERNAME}
        password: ${LOKI_PASSWORD}
```

I just get a 401 response.

```
 Chart version: 3.1.0
 Promtail version: 2.1.0
```

**EDIT**

Here is my ingress yaml:

```
controller:
  replicaCount: 1

  config:
    force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"

  service:
    targetPorts:
      http: http
      https: http
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123456:certificate/123456"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"

    enableHttp: false
    enableHttps: true
    type: LoadBalancer
    loadBalancerSourceRanges:
      - "0.0.0.0/0"

   ## Name of the ingress class to route through this controller
  ingressClass: nginx-external
```

...and my loki `values.yaml`

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-external"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: loki-ingress-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
  hosts:
    - host: loki.mydomain.com
      paths: 
        - "/"
  tls: []

config:
  auth_enabled: false
  ingester:
    chunk_idle_period: 3m
    chunk_block_size: 262144
    chunk_retain_period: 1m
    max_transfer_retries: 3
    lifecycler:
      ring:
        kvstore:
          store: inmemory
        replication_factor: 1
  
  schema_config:
    configs:
    - from: 2021-03-06
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: aws
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: loki_index_
        period: 24h
        
  server:
    http_listen_port: 3100

  storage_config:
    aws:
      bucketnames: my-bucket-name
      region: us-west-2
      s3forcepathstyle: true

    boltdb_shipper:
      active_index_directory: /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-active
      cache_location: /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-cache
      shared_store: s3

  chunk_store_config:
    max_look_back_period: 0s
  
  table_manager:
    retention_deletes_enabled: false
    retention_period: 0s

  compactor:
    working_directory: /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-compactor
    shared_store: aws

replicas: 1

podAnnotations:
  iam.amazonaws.com/role: "arn:aws:iam::123456:role/my-loki-role"

resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 500m
    memory: 2G
  requests:
    cpu: 250m
    memory: 1G

# The values to set in the PodDisruptionBudget spec
# If not set then a PodDisruptionBudget will not be created
podDisruptionBudget:
  minAvailable: 1
```

My logs from the nginx pod that Loki is sitting behind:

```
2021/03/09 04:23:44 [error] 37#37: *925 user "myusername": password mismatch, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: loki.mydomain.com, request: "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1", host: "loki.mydomain.com"
2021/03/09 04:23:44 [error] 37#37: *921 user "myusername": password mismatch, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: loki.mydomain.com, request: "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1", host: "loki.mydomain.com"
xx.xxx.xxx.xx - myusername [09/Mar/2021:04:23:44 +0000] "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1" 401 172 "-" "promtail/2.1.0" 326 0.000 [monitoring-loki-3100] [] - - - - 63294b16fe010a8c9ec1d4684f0472f5
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx: - myusername [09/Mar/2021:04:23:44 +0000] "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "promtail/2.1.0" 2744 0.003 [monitoring-loki-3100] [] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3100 0 0.004 204 029e0a9d1ee6242cad8b9a6d2ee50940
2021/03/09 04:23:44 [error] 37#37: *925 user "myusername": password mismatch, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xx, server: loki.mydomain.com, request: "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1", host: "loki.mydomain.com"
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx - myusername [09/Mar/2021:04:23:44 +0000] "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1" 401 172 "-" "promtail/2.1.0" 325 0.000 [monitoring-loki-3100] [] - - - - b75a2cfcf6c62b81953dd4fb26f1a844
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx - myusername [09/Mar/2021:04:23:44 +0000] "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "promtail/2.1.0" 1513 0.014 [monitoring-loki-3100] [] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3100 0 0.016 204 0049965a49877cb5d336ac6ec869feb4
2021/03/09 04:23:45 [error] 36#36: *941 user "myusername": password mismatch, client: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx, server: loki.mydomain.com, request: "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1", host: "loki.mydomain.com"
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx - myusername [09/Mar/2021:04:23:45 +0000] "POST /loki/api/v1/push HTTP/1.1" 401 172 "-" "promtail/2.1.0" 326 0.000 [monitoring-loki-3100] [] - - - - e5954bd055db5b3e9bd3227f57651847
```

Comment: did you have a look into the resulting ConfigMaps that helm produces? Is there the correct value?

Comment: @JensBaitinger Baitinger huh, promtail doesnt actually produce a configmap. However, I can SSH into the pod and the env vars are there, as well as the expected config file that references those env vars

Comment: What does the Nginx Ingress logs tell you? Could you share the Loki configuration and the Ingress yaml (stripped with any sensitive stuff)?

Comment: I did some tests and created this repo if it helps, i havent added anything related to `promtail` at the moment but the Ingress part might help if you're unsure about it: https://github.com/mikejoh/loki-basic-auth

Comment: @mikejoh I've updated my post with that requested info. My Nginx config looks pretty much the same as yours as well

Comment: @mikejoh huh, okay. so I noticed in the nginx logs that the username was set correctly, which was interesting; so I double-checked the password and sure enough, it was off by a few characters. Apparently having a "$" in the password was causing it to get saved as a secret improperly. I fixed the password, and now everything is running as expected. Wouldnt have noticed if you didn't mention checking the nginx logs, if you want to post your debugging steps as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @hhaslam11 Thanks, i'll add an answer! I wonder if you would've single quoted the password when creating the secret if the password would've worked for you? You can easily base64 decode the secret to see what was saved. Glad you got it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a bit of background to anyone new to Loki, as stated in the [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/authentication/): *Loki does not come with any included authentication layer. Operators are expected to run an authenticating reverse proxy in front of your services, such as NGINX using basic auth or an OAuth2 proxy.*

This basically means that you'll have to place something in between the client(s) and Loki to enforce e.g. basic authentication. In this case there's a Ingress (Nginx) acting as a reverse proxy with basic authentication.

To troubleshoot problems with authentication using Nginx there's a number of things to check:

- Logs of the Nginx Ingress Pod, check for authentication errors.
- That the added Kubernetes Secret contains what you expect.
- That you have configured the Ingress object with the needed `annotations`.

When it comes to using Nginx as Ingress and adding basic authentication [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/) resource from the official docs is really helpful.

In general when creating Kubernetes secrets, especially from the command line using `kubectl` you'll have to single quote the password if it contains special characters. This is so that the special characters wont be interpreted by your shell. More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kubectl/#create-a-secret).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and solved it with the original approach

- Separate secret (via sealed-secret)
- Env-variables.

Versions

| Chart-Version | App-Version |
| --- | --- |
| 6.15.1 | 2.8.4 |

My values.yaml

```
config:
  clients:
    - url: http://loki-gateway/loki/api/v1/push
      basic_auth:
        password: "${LOKI_PASSWORD}"
        username: "${LOKI_USERNAME}"

extraArgs:
  - -config.expand-env=true

extraEnv:
  - name: LOKI_USERNAME
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: promtail-credentials
        key: username
  - name: LOKI_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: promtail-credentials
        key: password

extraObjects:
  - apiVersion: bitnami.com/v1alpha1
    kind: SealedSecret
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sealedsecrets.bitnami.com/cluster-wide: "true"
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: promtail-credentials
      namespace: loki
    spec:
      encryptedData:
        username: <SEALED-VALUE-FOR-USERNAME-HERE>
        password: <SEALED-VALUE-FOR-PASSWORD-HERE>
      template:
        data: null
        metadata:
          annotations:
            sealedsecrets.bitnami.com/cluster-wide: "true"
          creationTimestamp: null
          name: promtail-credentials
          namespace: loki'
```